# How can I set the Text colour for this spinner that I have?

Tags: android, xml, spinner

```
 <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_statements"
            android:background="@drawable/file"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false" />
```

I want to know if there is anyway I could specify somewhere that I want the text colour of the items inside this spinner should be black.

java code ;

```
    final Spinner spinner= (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    String[] items = new String[]{"one", "two"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a xml called spinner_layout.xml with this code inside

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView  
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="20sp"
      android:gravity="left"  
      android:textColor="#FFFFF"         
      android:padding="5dip"
/>
```

And modify array adapter to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  (this,R.layout.spinner_layout, items);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create a layout file which copies `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml` and apply color you want.

let say **my_item.xml** as below.

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
android:textColor="@android:color/holo_purple"
android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

See `android:textColor` line added.

your java code now changed as below.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_item, items);
```

If you want to make different colors to each items or some rules, you have to create custom `Adapter` which inherited from `BaseAdapter` class.

Comment: I was having issues to follow what you were saying, and som errors. However thanks for the answer and it was helpful :)